# Capistrano, website unavailable during deployment

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, symfony4, capistrano3

I just figured out that the app i'm managing is unavailable during deploy. I thought capistrano built the new version of the app in a build folder before switching current with the new build at the end ? Isn't that it ?

I'm getting errors in logs when i try to access the website during deployment:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to write in the cache directory (/production/releases/20181127203847/var/cache/prod/twig/75)."
>
> php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Method Gregwar\ImageBundle\ImageHandler::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught RuntimeException: Asset manifest file "/production/releases/20181127203847/public/dist/manifest.json" does not exist.

I'm using Capistrano/Symfony and i dont understand why errors happen during these phases.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: I think you need a permission to cache directory.

Comment: Yeah, it was for case. This thread is solved btw. For those wondering, permission was set after symlink, causing these problems..